# node and npm not recognized in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

[image: I am using Hyper and I have tried reinstalling node, rebooting the system]

I am trying to create a new react-native application and this is the error that is thrown. Node is installed and so is npm. I have also set the PATH.

Comment: try restarting your pc once

Comment: I have restarted my system and also reinstalled node. This error occurs when I run the react-native init command otherwise I am able to use npm and node as intended.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the node to Environment variable**

To the end of your Path variable on the "User variable" section of the Environment Variables on the System Properties.

Example:

`;C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

Comment: I have done that too. As I have said I am able to run then elsewhere but this error is thrown only in case of react-native.